# Swift Function called from inside Asynchronous closure also Asynchronous?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

Say I have a Asynchronous closure and I call a function that I wrote inside of it.  Is this function going to be asynchronous or executed on the main queue?

```
AVCaptureStillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in

      self.myFunctionToDoSomething()          
})
```

I would like to know if my function takes a long time to execute, would it block my UI by being executed on the main queue?

Also where can I find information on the completion handler for this function or any other IOS function?  This is the page I looked at but it does not tell me if the handler is asynchronous or not and which queue it is on.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturestillimageoutput/1387374-capturestillimageasynchronously

Comment: It will execute on the same thread that the asynchronous closure is executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Asynchronous" and "executed on the main queue" are not mutually exclusive.  The `myFunctionToDoSomething` declaration will determine whether or not it's asynchronous, but without doing anything special it will be executed on whichever queue `captureStillImage...`'s callback is called on.  You can read the docs to see what that queue is, but if you want `myFunction` to be executed on a specific queue you have to declare that by saying:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.myFunctionToDoSomething()
}
```

Or if `myFunction...` is asynchronous, or will take a long time to execute:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    self.myFunctionToDoSomething()
}
```

Comment: So assuming myFunctionToDoSomething() will take a long time to execute I can assume that it won't block my UI?  Also where can I find the docs to see what the callback's queue is?

Comment: If it's going to take a long time, then do not run it on the main Queue.  Instead use the global queue:  DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.myFunctionToDoSomething()
        }

Comment: The documentation says that you should not assume the completion handler to run on a specific thread. Your solution makes it worse by always executing `myFunctionToDoSomething` on the main thread and thus block the UI. You should change it to `DispatchQueue.global().async { ... }`

Comment: Yes, if `myFunction...` is an asynchronous call itself, or if it is going to take a long time to execute, you will want to move it to a bg thread as @CodeDifferent mentions.  If anything in that function modifies UI elements you will need to move those portions to the main thread.